# Proposal: Handcraft integration with UX.SE so members can easily add HTML mockups to answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

Lately I've been making HTML mockups for some of my answers. Here are two examples:

- [Interactive table - with many levels of information](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/17107/249)
- [How to make a 20-field online form more user friendly?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/17009/249)

I've been using my product [Handcraft](http://handcraft.com), since that's what it's made for.

Sometimes people post screenshots or wireframes to assist in their answer. This is great, and it looks like we'll be [getting Balsamiq Mockups integration](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/647/can-stackexchange-license-balsamiq-for-mockups-on-ux-stackexchange) to assist with that part of answering questions.

HTML mockups can also contribute in a great way to answers. But there's no easy way to create a quick HTML mockup demonstrating some interaction or some screen design, and there's no easy way to make it editable by the community.

Handcraft could solve this problem. We could integrate with UX and allow members to easily create HTML mockups and post them in answers. They could even be collaborative, perhaps based on whether the answer is a community wiki or not.

I'm willing to initiate this process with Stack Exchange if the community here thinks it would be a valuable addition.

**What do you think? If this existed, would you use it? What kind of integration options would you be interested in? Do you think it could help improve the quality of answers throughout the site?**

Note that this would be **free**. I'd love to build this integration if it helps the community post better answers.

Answer (score 1):

While I think this would be great to have, I would worry that it might encourage the sorts of "giv3 me teh c0dez" that Stack Overflow deals with.

I'm also not too sure how much it would get used, since I know I don't typically have the time, as an answerer, to put that much effort into an answer most of the time. As an asker, however, it would be a great way to show complex UX issues.

Since UX isn't nearly as focused on code, I don't think this is as much of an issue, but if code *was* more of a focus for a particular question (for example, UX for accessibility scenarios and HTML markup), a more code-centric tool like jsFiddle would make more sense, since it surfaces the code more.

Fantastic tool though. I will definitely be giving it a much closer look the next time I am in a mode where it might help (deep in back-end things currently)

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't know HTML, so it would be pretty useless to me. But as had been discussed here several times, a very large part of the community seems to believe that a UX designer must know HTML - which I assume they do -  so I'm not very representative :).

In any case, kudos for the willingness to invest all that time and effort into it!